# Returning a dictionary using the shorthand of type [String: Int] in Swift

Tags: swift, dictionary

Why can't I return the dictionary `countDict` as shown:

I get the **error**:

> error: cannot convert return expression of type '[(key: String, value:
>   Int)]' to return type '[String : Int]'
>           return countDict.sorted(by: { $0.value > $1.value })

**code**:

```
let arr = ["red","green","green","black","blue","yellow","red","green","yellow","red","red","green"
            ,"green","grey","purple","orange","grey","blue","red","red","green","yellow","orange","purple","black","red"
            ,"blue","green","orange","blue","blue","white","yellow","blue","red","green","orange","purple","blue","black"]


func mostFrequentColor(arr: [String]) -> [String: Int] {
    guard arr.count != 0 else {return [:]}

    var countDict = [String: Int]()

    for color in arr {
        countDict[color] = (countDict[color] ?? 0) + 1
    }
    return countDict.sorted(by: { $0.value > $1.value })
}

print(mostFrequentColor(arr: arr))
```

Answer (score 0):

Dictionaries are unsorted by definition, hence `Dictionary.sorted(by:)` actually returns an array of tuples (consisting of the key-value pairs stored in the `Dictionary`, hence the error. If you pay close attention to what the error says, you'll see that the type you're trying to return is `[(key: String, val: Int)]`, which is a shorthand for `Array<(String,Int)>` instead of the expected type `[String:Int]`, which is a shorthand for `Dictionary<String,Int>`.

You can solve the error by simply removing the sorting. If you actually need the colors to be sorted, you'll need to use another data structure, since `Dictionary` is unsorted by definition.

You also don't need the `guard` statement, since you are creating `countDict` as an empty `Dictionary` anyways and the `for ... in` loop simply won't execute if `arr` has no elements. You can also use a shorthand syntax when modifying the values of your Dictionary.

```
func mostFrequentColor(arr: [String]) -> [String: Int] {
    var countDict = [String: Int]()
    for color in arr {
        countDict[color, default: 0] += 1
    }
    return countDict
}
```

Using a more functional approach, your function can actually be shortened to:

```
func mostFrequentColor(arr: [String]) -> [String: Int] {
    return colors.reduce(into: [String:Int](), { accumulatedResult, currentColor in
        accumulatedResult[currentColor, default: 0] += 1
    })
}

mostFrequentColor(arr: colorsArray) //["red": 8, "blue": 7, "grey": 2, "white": 1, "green": 8, "black": 3, "orange": 4, "purple": 3, "yellow": 4]
```